# Laravel and vue-resource: How to jump when ajax request has error?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel and vue-resource,in this demo below:

```
{
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('foo', 'bar');
  formData.append('pic', fileInput, 'mypic.jpg');

  this.$http.patch('/someUrl/'+itemId, formData,{
                    before(request) {
                        if (this.previousRequest) {
                            this.previousRequest.abort();
                        }
                        this.previousRequest = request;
                    }
                }).then((response) => {
                    this.items[index].price = response.data.price;
                }, (response) => {
                    //console.log(response.data);
                    window.location.href = "../../login";
                });
}
```

controller:

```
class CartController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $goods = Goods::findOrFail($id);
        $goods->amount = $request->get('amount');
        $goods->save();
        $price = Price::findOrFail($id);
        return $price;
    }
}
```

Ajax request access `update` method of `CartController`,
If login,ajax request is successful,it can work.
I want to let it jump to login page if login status is expired,
and I test it,the error in debugging tools is like this:

[image]

But the page doesn't jump.
How to let it jump?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your web routes under the `auth` middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    // Add all your non-api routes.

});
```

**This will not resolve the redirection after the callback**, but will prevent you to access to the page where the request is fired if you are not logged in, supposing that your form is in the same application that your API.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because of CSRF Token.

In your head section add this

```
<meta id="csrf-token" name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```

And in the Vue app file add this

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#csrf-token').getAttribute('content');
```

Regarding the redirection kindly share a bit more information as to the response from the server if the user is not authorised.

Comment: I add the code of controller and ajax request. There is no other response infomation in console.

Comment: So now you are not getting that error right Token Mismatch Exception

Answer (score 0):

Add your route url to VerifyCsrfToken.php file. So it will avoid token verification.

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
```

{

```
protected $except = [
    //url go here
];
```

}